# Using the Camera OK button

Tags: android-camera

I have written an app that allows the user to take a photo with the camera capture some other information then attach the photo to an email and send it.  But on the Motorola Droid the camera is started but the OK button will not return control to my application.  The cancel button is the action that will return control to my app, even the back button does not work either.

Is it more likely that this is a hardware or software problem and does anyone have any suggestions on how to debug and or solve this problem.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an Intent, this may be the source of the problem.  If you are using the API, I would make sure your layout is correct.

It would be helpful to know which level of the Android API you are targeting and which version of Android the Motorola Droid is running.  Have you tested this on other devices?  In the emulator?